# In C# is there anyway to read a property directly (versus having to loop through PropertyNames)

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I have the following code:

```
// Create a DirectorySearcher object.
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base;

// Use the FindOne method to find the user object.
SearchResult resEnt = mySearcher.FindOne();

foreach(string propKey in resEnt.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
   foreach (var property in resEnt.Properties[propKey])
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", propKey, property.ToString());
   }
}
```

This works fine but I only need to get a single property called "mail".  Is there anyway i can just read a single property without having to loop.  I am looking for something like this:

```
var emailAddress =  resEnt.Properties["mail"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want:

```
string emailAddress = (string)resEnt.Properties["mail"][0];
```

Note that you might want to do some checking here to make sure there is a valid "mail" property:

```
var mailProps = resEnt.Properties["mail"];
string emailAddress = mailProps.Count > 0 ? (string)mailProps[0] : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to work**

The example you have will return a single Property. The problem is that the return is a Collection. I recommend doing

```
// Or String if you know it's always a string
var mailCollection = resEnt.Properties["mail"].Cast<Object>(); 
var emailAddress = mailCollection.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you use `FirstOrDefault` it will return the first value or null. If you use `Single` or `[0]` you will have to perform a validation step before hand or catch the Exception that is thrown when no results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cast operation in conjuntion with LINQ to get the first object.

```
var email = resEnt.Properties["mail"].Cast<object>.FirstOrDefault();
```